# Strategy to maintain large table of backup catalogs per project in MySQL or PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, database-performance, database-partitioning

I am developing an LTO backup/restore solution based on gnu tar. 
We either keep the tapes inhouse, or the customer might buy these backups from us.
Hence the choice of a widely available, and free solution as opposed to a specific backup solution.
Since we dont know what type of backup solution customers might have.

The data to be backed-up can easily exceed a few million files, of which I need to create a catalog for file level restore.
Also, for the same project, we can have multiple backup sets, spanning work over multiple years
(Customers might start a project this year, require a backup and 2 years later, come back and do some more work  on it. So a new backup is needed)

Since the catalog table will grow VERY big in just a few months, I need to think about how to manage this table.
I thought partitions would be able to help me out on this.
But partitioning (or any other solution ) should not be based on dates , but on project.
I am afraid that the number of partitions might become an issue over time.

The database table structure is like this:

- project (id,name,etc...)
- job(id, jobname,project_id,etc...)
- tape(id, barcode,...)
- job_tape_lnk(job_id,tape_id)
- volume(id,volumename,tape_id)
- catalog(id,volume_id,filename,....)

I would like to partition table catalog by project.
Is this feasible? or do I need to look at another way of structuring my data?
I can use either MySQL or PostgreSQL, but have no hands on experience with partitioning

Answer (score 0):

In general, in PostgreSQL, table partitioning helps for certain kinds of bulk operations.  I don't think those apply to you so I will mention a few other things.

1. Partial indexes.  You could boost particularly large projects by giving them their own indexes, for example.  This is probably going to be at least as good as table partitioning in most workloads.
2. Look closely at your hardware.  I can't offer specifics here because you don't mention enough in terms of specifics to help there.
3. Be willing to look into more complex solutions if you need them, like Postgres-XC if your write load grows too large.
4. Be willing to bring in outside help if you get stuck.